# Hibernate does not flush persistence context before selection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to user hibernate with spring transaction support.I've configured session factory as bean(see below) and made a DAO class.I am also using spring test support -- running the test class with @Transactional annotation,which(as i understand) should allow me to call multiple dao operations in a single transaction.I read that hibernate should flush its persistence context either after commit or before a select is executed.I had my hopes on the latter.But most of my tests failed because(according to the logs) hibernate didn't flush it's persistence context after insert and before select.

Here is the spring part of the spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "repository")
public class DataAccessConfiguration {

 @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(pool());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("domain");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return hibernateProp;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("hibernate")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
        manager.setDataSource(pool());

        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("jdbc")
    PlatformTransactionManager jdbcTransactionManager(){
        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(pool());

        return manager;
    }
}
```

I am using two platform transaction managers -- one for jdbc and another for hibernate.I've tried deleting the jdbc manager leaving only hibernate(didn't work).

Here is the dao class:

```
@Repository
@Profile("hibernate")
public class UserDaoHibernate implements UserDao {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserDaoHibernate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void addRole(User user, Role role) {
        NativeQuery addRoleQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO roles(user_name, user_role) VALUES(:user_name,:user_role)");
        addRoleQuery.setParameter("user_name",user.getUsername());
        addRoleQuery.setParameter("user_role", role.toString().toUpperCase());
        addRoleQuery.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasRole(User user, Role role) {
        NativeQuery hasRoleQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM roles WHERE user_name = :user_name AND user_role = :user_role");
        hasRoleQuery.setParameter("user_name", user.getUsername());
        hasRoleQuery.setParameter("user_role", role.toString().toUpperCase());
        return hasRoleQuery.getResultList().size() == 1;
    }

}
```

The test code that fails with the test class is here :

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DataAccessConfiguration.class})
@Rollback
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("hibernate")
@Transactional
public class UserDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao sut;

    private User user = new User("NEW_USERNAME123", "NEW_PASSWORD123", LocalDate.now().minusYears(20),
            "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME");

    @Test
    public void shouldAddNewRoleToUser(){
        sut.insert(user);
        assertFalse(sut.hasRole(user,Role.MEMBER));

        sut.addRole(user, Role.MEMBER);

        assertTrue(sut.hasRole(user,Role.MEMBER));
    }

}
```

And here is the output i get afte running the test method(transaction comments not included):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('USER_ID_SEQUENCE')
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        roles 
    WHERE
        user_name = ? 
        AND user_role = ?
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ INSERT 
    INTO
        roles
        (user_name, user_role) 
    VALUES
        (?,?)
Nov 13, 2019 3:05:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
Nov 13, 2019 3:05:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: insert or update on table "roles" violates foreign key constraint "fk_roles_user_id"
  Detail: Key (user_name)=(NEW_USERNAME123) is not present in table "users_table".
```

When i programmatically commit the session with 
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit(); at end of insert everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make insert method @Transactional or use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush()

Answer (score 0):

You should make "shouldAddNewRoleToUser()" method annotated with @Transactional and also check have you configured spring session context in application for transactions.

Comment: @Transactional is on the Test Class which,according to documentation,should make all methods also transactional.

Comment: Annotating a test method with `@Transactional` causes the test to be run within a transaction that will, by default, be automatically rolled back after completion of the test. If a test class is annotated with `@Transactional`, each test method within that class hierarchy will be run within a transaction. Test methods that are not annotated with `@Transactional` (at the class or method level) will not be run within a transaction. Furthermore, tests that are annotated with `@Transactional` but have the propagation type set to NOT_SUPPORTED will not be run within a transaction.

Comment: By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after completion of the test; however, transactional commit and rollback behavior can be configured declaratively via the `@Commit` and `@Rollback` annotations at the class level and at the method level.

You can read the spring documentation here [https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html]

Comment: I did add it,even though i don't clearly understand why do i need that,it didn't do anything.Can you explain why do you think i need @Transactional on a test method?@Transactional is on the class method which means "At the class level, this annotation applies as a default to all methods of the declaring class and its subclasses.".I know that it works because i run the same test with spring jdbc.The problem here is not in transaction,or at least i don't see it there,but in that hibernate,for some reason that i don't understand,doesn't flush its context before selection.

Comment: Flushing context programmatically wokrs,but it should do it by deault.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only thing i found about my issue is here [How does AUTO flush strategy works](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Apparently the AUTO flush mode doesn't guarantee flush before EVERY query(At least not with hibernate own API).I am not 100% sure if this is my case,i'll try to find out.